# Dagger Hilt SingeltonComponent and Singelton

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I have a problem understanding one thing regarding Dagger Hilt. Let's say i have this simple module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object MyModule {

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideMyApi(retrofit: Retrofit): MyApi = return retrofit.create(MyApi::class.java)
    
}
```

When I annotate my module with SingeltonComponent, this means I will have one instance of this module throughout app's life, and its necessary, even though the module itself is "object" (therefore singelton) not a "class". Annotation is needed because module by default is not binded to anything, therefore system does not know, how long module's dependencies should be available.

Furthermore, I need to annotate my function with @Singelton if I want same instance of MyApi used every time when needed.

Is that correct or im missing something between the lines ?

Comment: you are doing it in the right way.